# Screenshot of UIViewController from XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, screenshot

I need to send the designer screenshots of the ViewController I'm working on. Usually I have to take multiple screenshots but I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to do it from Xcode. I can't run the app on simulator because it's under development.

Comment: Do you use IB to create the ViewController?

Comment: Simulator Screenshot   Command + s  and hall desktop Screen Sort   Command + Shift + number 4

Comment: [Link](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201361) containing detailed info about screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed app

1 Connect your device

2 Open XCode

3 Goto Windows - > Devices

4 select connected device from left side

[image]

click take screen shot

Answer (score 0):

For `ViewController` Try this:

Press `Command + Shift + number 4` and select the area on your screen to take screenshot.
it will save to your desktop automatically

For Simulator Try this:
open smulator Goto file click on save screenshot
Screenshot of your simulator automatically save to your desktop

Answer (score 0):

please try this for screen shot of simulator or view controller

You can use for the selected window screen shot Shift+Cammand+4

Answer (score 0):

When the device is connected and the app is running, click:

`Debug -> View Debugging -> Take Screenshot of [DEVICE]`

This will save a screenshot to the desktop.

You can also bind that function to a shortcut.